# Jquery: Change select box value and and activate a click state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, select

So whats going on is that I have a site that I have taken on for my work. I have two select boxes I am tying into. The problem is when you click the second select box and choose an option it uses ajax to load a second box next to it (a hierarchical select box). The code that I am using is simple and changes the value of the second box back to the "select" option state when the first box is changed. But what it is not doing is creating click state (sorry if I am saying that wrong) but in order for ajax to bring in and remove the third select box the second select box option needs to be clicked.

Is there a way for me to re-create a "click" of the select box.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(".state.form-select").change(function() {
  $('.hierarchical-select .form-select').val('select');
});
```

Here is a sample fiddle. [See this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agon024/vuvckm3u/4/)

Comment: You just need to manually trigger `click` event `$('.myFormElementClass').click();`

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, what exactly you are looking for but I feel that this should do the trick:

https://jsfiddle.net/vuvckm3u/5/

```
$(".state.form-select").change(function() {
    $('.hierarchical-select .form-select option:first-child').attr('selected', true);
});
```